# pocket pc programming in C#

Tags: c#

How I can start pocket pc programming in C#
Please I want any link to start

Comment: Simple things like this should really be Google'd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a good one: [.NET Compact Framework Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa497273.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

PocketPC has been rebranded by Microsoft in later version as "Windows Mobile". Here's a link to their [developer center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/default.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Also be aware that the new versions of windows phone are going to use a combination of silverlight and XNA so anything you learn from the above links is going to be for legacy systems.

If this is something you are doing for yourself I would possibly hold off until it is known what will happen to the legacy systems. I am still unsure if WinMo 7 is going to be marketed to large companies but judging by the success of the iPhone it could very well be.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to search for the .NET Compact Framework. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compact_Framework)'s the wiki article that will give basic information about it (and some links).

And [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa497273.aspx)'s the MSDN page for it.